# Prevent NHibernate from aliasing in ORDER BY

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, criteria, icriteria

I have a query which has an Order By clause. The generated SQL from NHibernate looks like

```
 ORDER BY coalesce(x.Company as x__.Company, y.Company) asc
```

This fails as 'as' is not allowed in Order by clause in MS SQL Server. Is there any way I can prevent aliasing?

The criteria query that I have written looks like:

```
 var orderBy = Projections.SqlFunction("coalesce", NHibernateUtil.String,      
                       Projections.ProjectionList() 
                      .Add(Projections.Property("x.Company"))
                      .Add(Projections.Property("y.Company")));

 var order = Order.Asc(orderBy);
 criteria.AddOrder(order);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Projections.SqlFunction("coalesce",
                        NHibernateUtil.String,
                        Projections.Property("x.Company"),
                        Projections.Property("y.Company"));
```

The parameters to the coalesce (or any other) function should be passed separately (actually, as a params array), not merged into a ProjectionList.

Comment: Thanks Diego! That helped. I was struck with this one for a while.

Comment: Hi I am facing similar problem. But instead function I am adding conditional sort columns in projections list and in last providing to Orderby() where getting this "AS" breaking the SQL. I need to have all sort by columns using many conditions. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar annoying problems. You might have to derive a class from PropertyProjection and use that inplace of Projections.Property(). Override the ToSqlString method and strip out the AS clause.

Comment: Tim,
What should the override be? 

I attempted something like:

        public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria,  
        int loc, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary<string,
         IFilter> enabledFilters)
        {
           return new SqlString(this.PropertyName);
         }


But this threw an exception:
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  Message=length should be greater than or equal to 0

Comment: Or for that matter, in the override I provided


   return new SqlString(new string[]{this.PropertyName});



I received the same ArgumentException